# tagName key in backbone.js view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm currently working on a project where I'm implementing Backbone.js View. I want to dynamically create html tag in the view but everything I tried so far does not work. Is there a new version of backbone that change the synax? because I watched a tutorial and it work for the guy but unfornately it did not work for me. This is what I have right now:

```
//My view for one book

var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({

    model: new Book(),
    tagName: function () {
        return this.model.get('tr');
    },         
    initialize: function () {
        this.template = _.template($('.books-list-template').html());
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

I also tried this:

```
//My view for one book

var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({

    model: new Book(),
    tagName: 'tr',         
    initialize: function () {
        this.template = _.template($('.books-list-template').html());
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: `tagName: 'tr'` should give you a `<tr>` in `this.$el`. What's in your template? What happens when you try to use your view?

Comment: @muistooshort When I use the view, nothing shows up in the table but when I inspect element in the console, the json object is there but no tr tag is being created or appended to the table.

Comment: Are you adding the view's `el` to your `<table>` anywhere?

Comment: Yea, that was the problem but I figured it out earlier. I forgot to add to the table. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example *should* work but let's just keep it to the basics:

```
var ViewWithTRTagNameClass = Backbone.View.extend({tagName: 'tr'});
var viewWithTRTagName = new ViewWithTRTagNameClass();

console.log(viewWithTRTagName.render().el); // or alert, or $('body').append, etc.
```

Okay, so that worked.

Your second example is more complicated but essentially the same as this because your `render` function returns `this`. So, it should have a `tr` element wrapping the inner content.

By the way, `View`'s `tagName` is calculated at the time you instantiate it - this takes place inside of `_ensureElement`.

If you want to re-calculate the element - say, before your first `render` - you can call `view._ensureElement();` at the appropriate time and after the appropriate checks have been made.